# I am having trouble making a grade calculator that loops. It must display the invalid input message and repeat if the input is wrong

Tags: python, loops, calculator

**** Please let me know what is wrong with my code. I am trying to figure out how to get it to loop if the input is invalid. I am new to python and every answer helps. Thank you!****

```
MIN_GPA=0
MAX_GPA=4

term_grade_point= float(input("Term grade point (0-4): "))

while ((term_grade_point>MIN_GPA) and (term_grade_point<MAX_GPA)):

    if ((term_grade_point >= 0 and term_grade_point <0.85 )):
        print("F")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 0.85 and term_grade_point < 1.15)):
        print ("D") 
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 1.15 and term_grade_point <1.5)):
        print ("D+")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 1.5 and term_grade_point < 1.85)):
        print ("C-")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 1.85 and term_grade_point < 2.15)):
        print ("C")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 2.15 and term_grade_point < 2.5)):
        print ("C+")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 2.5 and term_grade_point < 2.85)):
        print ("B-")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 2.85 and term_grade_point < 3.15)):
        print ("B")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 3.15 and term_grade_point < 3.5)):
        print("B+")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 3.5 and term_grade_point < 3.85)):
        print ("A-")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 3.85 and term_grade_point <4.00)):
        print ("A")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 4.00)):
        print ("A+")
    
    else:
        print("\nOutside range 0 - 4\n")
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you see this solution?

```
MIN_GPA=0
MAX_GPA=4
while True:
    term_grade_point= float(input("Term grade point (0-4): "))

    if ((term_grade_point >= 0 and term_grade_point <0.85 )):
        print("F")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 0.85 and term_grade_point < 1.15)):
        print ("D") 
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 1.15 and term_grade_point <1.5)):
        print ("D+")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 1.5 and term_grade_point < 1.85)):
        print ("C-")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 1.85 and term_grade_point < 2.15)):
        print ("C")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 2.15 and term_grade_point < 2.5)):
        print ("C+")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 2.5 and term_grade_point < 2.85)):
        print ("B-")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 2.85 and term_grade_point < 3.15)):
        print ("B")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 3.15 and term_grade_point < 3.5)):
        print("B+")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 3.5 and term_grade_point < 3.85)):
        print ("A-")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point>= 3.85 and term_grade_point <4.00)):
        print ("A")
        
    elif (( term_grade_point == 4.00)):
        print ("A+")
    
    else:
        print("\nOutside range 0 - 4. Please, try again\n")
        continue

    break
```

The point is that you iterate forever till you find a valid input and when it is invalid, you ask for a new value.